# Missing or Invalid option error when running a plsql block

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I get an ORA-00922 'Missing or invalid option' when running this SQL block and can't figure out why. I've tried looking for specific syntax error (an errant bracket) but nothing works:

```
DECLARE
  v_original_profiles SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
  v_original_usernames SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;           
  modified_ddl varchar2(400);
  username varchar2(100);
BEGIN

  SELECT profile, username
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_original_profiles, v_original_usernames      
  FROM dba_users
  WHERE profile in ('profile_x');

  FOR i IN 1 .. v_original_usernames.COUNT LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER USER ' || v_original_usernames(i) || ' PROFILE Profile_A';
  END LOOP;

  FOR r IN (WITH t AS (
              SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('USER', username) ddl
              FROM dba_users
              WHERE profile in 'Profile_A' OR username IN (SELECT username FROM smith.emp))            
            SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTR(ddl, 1, INSTR(ddl, 'DEFAULT') - 1), 'CREATE', 'ALTER') || ';' AS modified_ddl
            FROM t) 
LOOP
    BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE r.modified_ddl;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error executing: ' || r.modified_ddl || '. ' || SQLERRM);
    END;
  END LOOP;

  FOR i IN 1 .. v_original_usernames.COUNT LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER USER ' || v_original_usernames(i) || ' PROFILE ' || v_original_profiles(i);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Error at line 1
ORA-06550: line 9, column 5:
PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
ORA-06550: line7, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Script stopped on line 1.

Thanks! I added the additional variable and replaced the execute immediates with dbms_output_line and it displays the code as intended. However when converting back to the execute immediates i get an ora-00922: missing or invalid option at line 5 and ORA-06512 at line 16

Error at line 5
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
ORA-06512: at line 15

Comment: Since it's PL/SQL, the error message should also state which line is causing the error. Can you [edit] your question and post the **entire** error message(s) that you are getting?

Comment: Dynamic SQL can be tricky; if you didn't do that until now, replace all EXECUTE IMMEDIATE calls with DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE to display commands you'll execute. Then, you might notice what is wrong at first sight or - if not - run statements manually to see how Oracle responds.

Comment: Is `SELECT profile` supposed to be `SELECT username`? Passing a profile name into `alter user` doesn't look right... But the DDL you're trying to run in the cursor loop doesn't make sense - you're taking the whole `create user` statement and changing that to `alter user <username>;` - you're losing everything from `default` onwards, and adding a semicolon that should not be there - which will throw that error. That should be obvious from your exception handler?  It's unclear what you're actually trying to achieve though - what are you trying to alter for each user?

Comment: Remove those EXECUTE IMMEDIATES, and follow what Littlefoot said. 
Do not run this code on any database- its just unpredictable and possibly dangerous.

Comment: Thanks, to further clarify, this script would circumvent user profile limitations in order to reapply user passwords after a db refresh. I've currently edited the query to include the complete error code and modified the bulk collect to include username..

Answer (score 0):

First note: take the advice in the comments on your question regarding dynamic SQL seriously.

Secondly, your error is in the use of `v_original_profiles SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;`. This is an array of singular `VARCHAR2` values. In the first loop you try to `BULK COLLECT` two values in one array value.

Solution: use 2 arrays to `BULK COLLECT` your query results.

```
DECLARE
  v_original_profiles  SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
  v_original_usernames SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
BEGIN
  SELECT profile, username
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_original_profiles, v_original_usernames
  FROM dba_users
  WHERE profile in ('profile_x');
END;
```

Comment: Thanks! I modified the query and replaced the execute immediates with dbms_output_line and it displays the code as intended. However when converting back to the execute immediates i get an ora-00922: missing or invalid option at line 5 and ORA-06512 at line 16

Comment: What happens when you run the code that is displayed by `dbms_output` by hand in another tool (for example SQL Developer or sqlplus)? Does that work or not?